# check if collection of objects where each contain another collection of objects contain all values of List<string> via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects where each object contains another collection of objects. I need to find out the fastest way to check if it contains all values of `List<string>`.

Here is an example:

```
class Video {        
  List<Tag> Tags; 
}

class Tag{
  public Tag (string name){
    Name = name;
  }

  string Name;
}

List<string> selectedTags = new List<string>();
selectedTags.Add("Foo");
selectedTags.Add("Moo");
selectedTags.Add("Boo");

List<Video> videos = new List<Video>();

// Case A
Video videoA = new Video();
videoA.Tags = new List<Tag>();
videoA.Tags.Add(new Tag("Foo"));
videoA.Tags.Add(new Tag("Moo"));
videos.Add(videoA);
```

`videoA` **should not** be selected by LINQ because it doesn't contain all tags.

```
// Case B
Video videoB = new Video();
videoB.Tags = new List<Tag>();
videoB.Tags.Add(new Tag("Foo"));
videoB.Tags.Add(new Tag("Moo"));
videoB.Tags.Add(new Tag("Boo"));
videos.Add(videoB);
```

`videoB` **should** be selected by LINQ because it contains all tags.

I tried this with `foreach` loops, but it's too slow so I'm looking for a LINQ solution.

```
foreach (Video video in videos) {
  if (video.Tags.Count() > 0) {
    bool containAllTags = true;
    foreach (string tagToFind in selectedTags) {
      bool tagFound = false;
      foreach (Tag tagItem in video.Tags) {
        if (tagToFind == tagItem.Name)
          tagFound = true;
      }
      if (!tagFound)
        containAllTags = false;
    }
    if (containAllTags)
      result.Add(videoItem);
  }
}
```

The resulting LINQ should look like this:

```
IEnumerable<Video> = from vid in videos
                     where vid.Tags.( ..I dont know.. )
                     select vid;
```

I tried several ways with `.Any`, `.All`, etc.. but I can't find the solution and I can't use `.Intersect` because one is a `List` of strings and the other is a `List` of objects. Note that in the production version, `Video` and `Tag` elements have many more properties.

Comment: Is order of the tags important or are you treating these as sets?

Comment: No the order is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, you *logically* want:

```
IEnumerable<Video> result = from vid in videos
                            where selectedTags.All(tag =>
                                     vid.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tag))
                            select vid;
```

Or equivalently:

```
var result = videos.Where(vid => selectedTags.All(tag => 
                                      vid.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tag)));
```

This is assuming you've made `Tag.Name` and `Video.Tags` public, of course - ideally as properties rather than as fields.

Note how we're calling `All` against `selectedTags`, as (assuming I've read your requirements correctly) it's important that all the selected tags are present in the video - it's *not* important that all the video's tags are selected.

Now that could be relatively slow, if you have a lot of tags to check and a lot of tags per video.

However, knowing how to optimize it will really depend on some other choices:

- If the order of the tags isn't important, could you change `Video.Tags` to be a set instead of a list?
- Are you always looking through the same set of videos, so you could perform some pre-processing?
- Is the total number of tags available large? What about the number of tags per video? What about the number of selected tags?

Alternatively, you can project each video to its "list of tags" and check whether there are any in the selected set which aren't in the video's set:

```
var result = videos.Where(vid => !selectedTags.Except(vid.Tags.Select(t => t.Name))
                                              .Any());
```

Comment: The `vid.Tags.` might need projecting because the `selectedTags` is down as a `List<string>` whereas the inner collection is a `List<Tag>` (so the current `Contains` won't work).

Comment: I dont think so becouse in "selectedTags.All(tag" > "tag" is string but here "vid.Tags.Contains(tag))" > "tag" has to be Tag object so it cant be equal to string. Your solution would work if Video would have List<string> Tags. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: @OselMikoDřevorubec: Ah, I hadn't noticed this. I foolishly expected a variable called `selectedTags` to be a `List<Tag>` rather than a `List<string>`. Can you fix your code to make the data model more consistent?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Well I've fixed my answer so that it will work with the current setup, but I still think it would be *cleaner* to avoid having one collection of strings and one collection of `Tag` objects. Consistency makes code cleaner :)

Comment: Well i think that is obvious from Question name and description that i need to compare it with List<string>...

Comment: @OselMikoDřevorubec: Well, I clearly missed it - I've fixed the code in the answer anyway, but I still think you'd be better off trying to approach this with a more consistent model. Is there any reason you *don't* have a consistent model?

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, just thought it was funny :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well i have writen "Note that in the production version, Video and Tag elements have mutch more properties." That meen the Video and Tag objects here are just for ilustration of problem but in real they have mutch more properties and there is no sence to create list of Tags from selectedTags becouse i miss other values to make them equal and also i need Tags in Video elemenet becouse of this values :-)

Comment: @OselMikoDřevorubec: Okay, that makes more sense... although I'd then suggest using `selectedTagNames` as a variable name instead of `selectedTags`.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes im sorry for this but if this is only unclear thing in my question i can live with that :-)